# Batch Update/insert in using SQLCommand in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I could achieve batch `update/insert` using `SQLCommand`. I wanted to create `SQLCommand` text dynamically in `for` loop of `MyObject[]` in C# with 10 `SQLParameter`

in case of bulk `insert`, i need to check for every record that it already exist or not. i.e.

`if not Exists(select pkid from table1 where fkid1=@fkid1 and fkid2=@fkid1)`

`begin`

```
insert....
```

`end`

This is to be done from C#.No stored procedure in db

Comment: I need both in C# only.SQL procedures not allowed as per requirements

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
// Set connection, etc.
for(int i=0; i< items.length; i++) {
    command.CommandText += string.Format("update mytable set s_id=@s_id{0} where id = @id{0};", i);
    command.Parameters.Add("@s_id" + i, items[i].SId);
    command.Parameters.Add("@id" + i, items[i].Id);
}
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I clarified question,please review it

Answer (score 10):

**Edited** Warning: this answer, albeit partially correct, does not address the issue asked, in fact `ExecuteNonQuery` submits the workload to the database (this can be proved by writing an incorrect query: the exception is thrown on `ExecuteNonQuery` and not on `Commit`).

Only to append all `CommandTexts` to one big batch command is not as useful as it seems to be.

The main benefit of prepared statements in C# is, that the workload in the database is done while creating the command. Not, when you execute it [e.g. with `ExecuteNonQuery()` - which executes the command only if you don't have a transaction object created].

To avoid this and to create the workload in the database only once for all your statements, it's significant better to create a `Transaction` object and to commit this transaction. Then all commands will be executed without any more workload in the database.

This would be a better approach:

```
// Try to create the Command as early as possible with a valid Connection object
string commandString = "UPDATE Mytable SET s_id=@s_id where id = @id;";
var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);

// Then define a Transaction object with your Connection
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
command.Transaction = transaction;

// Now iterate through your array
for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
  command.Parameters.Add("@s_id", SqlDbType.YourType).Value = items[i].SId;
  command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.YourType).Value = items[i].Id;
  command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Not executed at this point
}

// And now execute it with the possibility to rollback all commands when it fails
try {  transaction.Commit(); } // Here the execution is committed to the DB
catch (Exception)
{
  transaction.Rollback();
  throw;
}
```

Comment: sql statement in a var called connectionString? wtf

Comment: I have changed the name 'connectionString' in 'commandString'. This should be a better naming, doesn't it?

Comment: What if i use executeScalar??  Return value??

Comment: is there official documentation from Microsoft that states that the executenonquery would not make the application start transferring the query from the app server to the db server until the commit is called?

Comment: `command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Not executed at this point` that is incorrect. it is executed and send to the server even when executed with a connection that has a transaction. tested using sqlprofiler

Comment: edited the answer to reflect the comments. if someone has a link to a proper solution, please add the link in the answer.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here. You should do a Parameters.Clear() for each iteration of adding new parameters. What I've done is an Add for each parameter before the loop without the values and inside the loop just set the parameter values.

Answer (score 3):

[SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is rather handy for situations such as these.

Answer (score 1):

That is my fast solution for testing fast batch-transaction inserting.

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringFromSecret(args)))
        {
            conn.Open();

            stopwatch.Start();
            long counter = 0;
            var tran = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn, tran);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            int batch_param_counter = 0;
            foreach (var chars_table in table_of_table_of_chars)
            {
                var key = string.Concat(chars_table);//get 1st param
                var hash = BitConverter.ToString(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();//get 2nd param

                cmd.CommandText += $"insert into hash_table([key], hash) values(@key{batch_param_counter}, @hash{batch_param_counter});{Environment.NewLine}";
                var param_key = new SqlParameter("@key" + batch_param_counter, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                param_key.Value = key;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param_key);
                var hash_key = new SqlParameter("@hash" + batch_param_counter, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 32);
                hash_key.Value = hash;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(hash_key);
                batch_param_counter++;

                if (counter % 200 == 0)
                {
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn, tran);
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    batch_param_counter = 0;
                }

                if (counter % 20000 == 0)
                {
                    if (cmd != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd.CommandText))
                    {
                        cmd.Prepare();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn, tran);
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        batch_param_counter = 0;
                    }
                    tran.Commit();
                    tran = null;

                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                        break;

                    cmd.Transaction = tran = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
                }
                counter++;
            }

            if (cmd != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd.CommandText))
            {
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            if (tran != null)
                tran.Commit();

            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: batching insert every 200 items

Answer (score 0):

you can send your values as comma separated string into as stored procedure parameters then split them using `Split()` sql function.

try this

```
    StringBuilder Par1 = new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder Par2 = new StringBuilder("");
    for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Par1.Append(",");
            Par2.Append(",");
        }
        Par1.Append(MyObject[i].Prop1);
        Par2.Append(MyObject[i].Prop2);
    }
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Par1", Par1.ToString()));
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Par2", Par2.ToString()));
    myCommand.CommandText = "MyStoredProcedure";
    myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

your stored procedure will look like this

```
CREATE Procedure MyStoredProcedure
(
    @Par1 as varchar(max),
    @Par2 as varchar(Max)
)
AS
create table #AllValues
 (  
value1 varchar(50),
value2 varchar(50)
  );

 create table #Par1s
 (  
id integer, 
data varchar(50)
 );

 create table #Par2s
 (  
id integer, 
data varchar(50)
 );
 insert into #Par1s select * from dbo.Split (@Par1,',')
 insert into #Par2s select * from dbo.Split (@Par2,',')

Insert into #AllValues(value1,value2)
Select #Par1s.data,#Par2s.data From #Par1s Inner Join #Par2s On #Par1s.ID = #Par2s.ID


Insert into myTable(Col1,Col2)
Select value1,value2 from #AllValues
```

you can pass any number of paramters using the same approach in `Insert` or `Update`

Comment: everything is done in C#, No stored procedure allowed as per requirement.

Comment: I cannot understand No stored procedure role but anyway why don't use `Linq to sql` or `Entity Framework` that more efficient than writing `sql statement` in your code

Comment: This project in stage of maintenance. We can not implements new in it(only corrections)